Power Supply Lightning Protection - Waveform 5A in DO-160
I am working on protecting a 28V power supply from lightning-induced surges. According to the DO-160 standard, the test limit for this design is set at 1600V/1600A. While I am aware of using TVS diodes and MOVs for protection, I am curious if there are other effective lightning protection techniques available.


